# How to add throw in the network operation workflow

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation, and having difficulties to throws if there any issues happen during the following workflow. As you see in my code, I either return nil or does not return anything, wondering how to handle these scenario.

```
enum ContentServiceError: Error {
  case EncodingError
  case URLInvalidError
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  postContent(id: id, content: content) { (error) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        // handle throw here
    }
  }
}

func postContent(
    id: String?,
    content: String,
    completion: @escaping(Error?) -> ()
  ) {
    guard
      let id = id,
      let url =  URL(string: "\(baseURL)\(contentEndPoint)\(id)"),
      let contentData = contentData(from: Content(id: id, content: content)),
    else {
      // how to add throw here
      return
    }
    let request = Request(headers: nil, httpMethod: .post, httpBody: contentData, parameters: nil, url: url)
    let networkHandler = NetworkHandler(urlSession: URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral))
    networkHandler.dataRequest(request, successHandler: { data in
      completion(nil)
    }, failureHandler: { error in
      completion(error)
    })
  }


 private func contentData(content: Content) -> Data? {
    var content: Data
    do {
      let encoder = JSONEncoder()
      contentData = try encoder.encode(content)
    } catch {
      // how to add throw here 
      return nil
    }
    return contentData
  }
```

Comment: Instead of throwing just a generic error better to throw the error returned by the encoder

Comment: @LeoDabus, would you mind to add your answer here please? I love your approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the function to throw and remove the catch

```
private func contentData(content: Content) throws -> Data {
  var content: Data
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  return try encoder.encode(content)
}
```

Then of course you need to decide what to do with the calling function, should it also throw the error or use a do/catch and handle it, maybe call the completion handler with the error

```
do { 
  let contentData = try contentData(from: Content(id: id, content: content))
} catch {
  completion(error)
  return
}
```

I see no point in having `id` as an optional only to throw an error if it is nil, make it non-optional instead. For the url creation you can have a similar handling as above

```
guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseURL)\(contentEndPoint)\(id)") } else {
  completion(ContentServiceError.URLInvalidError)
  return
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. Actually my problem is how to handle this throw in the completion handler, in other words from caller method to all the way to the up to the thread. voted up your answer.

Comment: Do I need to put `do-catch` inside the `guard` statement?

Comment: I should add `try` in the following line, right? `let contentData = try contentData`

Comment: Also need to add return type which is `Data?` as follows? `contentData(content: Content) throws -> Data?`

Comment: the return type is `Data?` or `Data`

Comment: It is Data since the function will either return a Data object or throw an error but it will never return nil

Comment: `var content: Data`
  `let encoder = JSONEncoder()`
  `return try encoder.encode(content)` doesn't make any sense. If it is already data why would you need to encode it? Note that if it is `Data` it will by default convert it to base64. What OP really need is to make the method generic and constrain the generic type to `Encodable` protocol.

Comment: `func contentData<C: Encodable>(content: C) throws -> Data { try JSONEncoder().encode(content) }`